# Long lasting food category naming

Tags: word-request

What do you call a category of groceries that lasts long? Examples include food in cans, rice, pasta, cereals, chocolate.

Suggestions:

1. durables
2. durable food
3. durable food products category
4. long-lasting food

Comment: At least one UK supermarket calls them **store cupboard**. Items that have distant or no use by date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such foods are called **nonperishable** (also written as **non-perishable**). [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/nonperishable) gives this definition:

> Nonperishable food does not decay quickly.